# How can I detect user seeked in react-native-vimeo-iframe

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Now I working with react-native-vimeo-iframe. I do not how to catch event if user seeked the video and not allow for this. If user seeked video, it will return the previous time of video.

I have try the event seeked and seeking of library but not work